# Android Studio UI: TextView position shift after ImageView resize

Tags: java, android, android-studio, user-interface, layout

[image]

My second lines TextView is received text, if received text length more than one line, it will resize ImageView.

After ImageView resize the TextView should be on H's corners(the four red circle), but it will shift  to other position.

I try other Layout like FrameLayout, or set TextView's constraint widget to parent or ImageView, but final result is same.

How to keepe TextView on ImageView's position even if ImageView resize?

My layer structure:

```
linearlayout(Divider)
linearlayout
    btn_1
    btn_2
    btn_3 
linearlayout(Divider)
ConstraintLayout
    ConstraintLayout
        ImageView
        TextView_1
        TextView_2
        TextView_3
        TextView_4
    linearlayout
        linearlayout
            btn_1
            btn_2
            btn_3
        linearlayout
            ....
```

Code:

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/chair"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"


            android:text="0"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.28"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.101" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="0"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.28"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="0"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.702"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.101" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="0"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.702"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.898" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should to position texts depended to image like this(for example in below text will positioned to top and left corner of imageView):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.517"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="T"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.311"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks your help, but it's not work. Setting TextView's constraint widget to parent or ImageView are same result.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do here is use [Guideline](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/Guideline), Guidelines are small visual helpers to design layouts with. Views can be aligned to a guideline which can simplify layouts, especially if you have the same margin values duplicated on a lot of elements. This is helpful and really solve many of my issue design and simplifications :)

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="342dp"
            android:layout_height="344dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/chair"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.28"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.101" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="0"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.702"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.101" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"

            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="0"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.28"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.898" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="0"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.702"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.898" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```